# How will Linq DataContext.SubmitChanges() work internally?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How will the `DataContext` remember changes internally. What happens if I call `SubmitChanges()` more than once. If there was an exception while calling `SubmitChanges()`, is there a way to clear all the changes from the `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) you can do this using transactions